# React Native: Resize custom UI component

Tags: android, react-native

I've built a very simple native Android UI component and I want to update the size of its child view when a button from my react native project is clicked. To be more precise, when this button is clicked then I send a command to my `SimpleViewManager` which in turn calls the `resizeLayout()` of my custom view.

I can verify that the `resizeLayout()` is properly called but the layout is not resized **until I rotate the phone**. Obviously, changing the device's orientation triggers the `draw()` of my custom view but so does the `invalidate()` which I explicitly call.

Other layout changes like changing the background color instead of resizing it work fine.

My custom component looks like this:

```
public class CustomComponent extends RelativeLayout {
    public CustomComponent(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.simple_layout, this);
    }

    public void resizeLayout(){
        LinearLayout childLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.child_layout);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) childLayout.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = 50;
        layoutParams.width= 50;
        childLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        invalidate();
    }
}
```

and the simple_layout.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/child_layout"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#ffee11"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After a couple of days of searching, I finally found the answer in [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4990) old reported issue in React Native's repo.

This solution is the same as the ones used in [ReactPicker.java](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/picker/ReactPicker.java) and [ReactToolbar.java](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/toolbar/ReactToolbar.java). I had to put the following code in my CustomComponent and after that there is no need to even call `requestLayout()` or `invalidate()`. The changes are propagated as soon as I update my layout's LayoutParams.

```
@Override
public void requestLayout() {
    super.requestLayout();

    // The spinner relies on a measure + layout pass happening after it calls requestLayout().
    // Without this, the widget never actually changes the selection and doesn't call the
    // appropriate listeners. Since we override onLayout in our ViewGroups, a layout pass never
    // happens after a call to requestLayout, so we simulate one here.
    post(measureAndLayout);
}

private final Runnable measureAndLayout = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getHeight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        layout(getLeft(), getTop(), getRight(), getBottom());
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Helped me solve issue of custom-added-using-java views not getting updated in the hierarchy. (just put your custom views in a container with the above method overrides)

Comment: Oh actually, for my case there's one more step apparently: after adding the above container view (which I had inherit from RelativeLayout), call ```container.layout(0, 0, width, height);``` on it.

Comment: This helped me a lot, our library was stuck at width:0, height:0 because apparently requestLayout in ReactNative app is not very useful. Adding a bounty.

Comment: This really helped me! Thanks!

Comment: @George: I am also try to use jwplayer with react-native and i am facing same issue in ios. Have you and idea how to fixed it.

Comment: @BhaveshJariwala no, sorry. On iOS it worked just fine for me. Try asking a new question and if you send me the link I'll see what I've done differently.

Comment: @George: I will create a separate issue and add code there. But how can i send you link? If you can share ios and react-native code then . it will be helpful

Comment: @George: Here is task that you ask me to create: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53096720/how-to-make-jwplayer-fullscreen-in-react-native

All the details mentioned in that task. can you please look in to it.

Comment: I can't believe that in 2019, React Native still doesn't have a mention in their docs about this issue. I wasted hours on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
requestLayout();
```

instead of invalidate.

This post also has some good information on view lifecycle.

[Usage of forceLayout(), requestLayout() and invalidate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856180/usage-of-forcelayout-requestlayout-and-invalidate)

I would also recommend changing your root element in your view xml to

```
<merge>
```

that way your CustomComponent class doesn't have a RelativeLayout as its immediate child, unless that's what you were going for.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. Using `<merge>` is actually a good idea. However, I've already tried calling all the above methods both in my CustomComponent as well as on the childLayout. The code works fine in an Android project. The problem appears when I use it in combination with React Native.