# JWPlayer+ReactNative+Android: black screen with audio

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, jwplayer

I'm trying to create a react-native plugin for JWPlayer and right now (in the android part) I can see the video on the screen (in the location defined by the react view) and even its buttons, but when I play the video I see a black screen while the music plays in the background.
The curious thing is that when I put the JWPlayerView into WindowManager the video is properly displayed on a full screen in the center.

What am I doing wrong?

this is the react-native code:

```
<View>
    <JWPlayer 
        style={{width: 320, height: 240}}
        src='http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4' />
</View>
```

Comment: [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39836356/react-native-resize-custom-ui-component/39838774#39838774) solved my problem.

Comment: I have also integrated JWplayer using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-jw-media-player. But for screen become empty. I can't see anything on the screen.