# Child Components in Native Android view does not resize correctly

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, kotlin

I have created `native android view` and it needs to wrap child components from `react-native`

I am using a `TouchableOpacity` as a child to the `native android view` which I created. When the screen loads the `TouchableOpacity` takes the whole width and height and which is not what I want but as soon as I comment and uncomment the width style of `TouchableOpacity` it relayout correctly. So in short as soon as Fast refresh is done the layout looks proper, not sure what the issue here is. Even giving a fix height to `TouchableOpacity` does not work

Layout when the app first loads

[image]

Layout when fast refresh is done by commenting and uncommenting the `TouchableOpacity's` width

[image]

Here is the code

```
class CealGradientView(context: Context): LinearLayout(context){

    fun configureViews(color: ReadableArray){
        val layoutParams: ViewGroup.LayoutParams =
            LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        setLayoutParams(layoutParams)


        val colorsCollection: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()
        for (i in 0 until color.size()) {
            colorsCollection.add(Color.parseColor(color.getString(i)))
        }
        val colors = colorsCollection.stream().mapToInt { i -> i }.toArray()
        val gradientDrawable = GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
            colors
        )
        background = gradientDrawable
}

class CealGradientManager(private val reactApplicationContext: ReactApplicationContext):
    ViewGroupManager<CealGradientView>() {

    private val cealGradientView = "CealGradientView"

    override fun getName() = cealGradientView

    override fun createViewInstance(reactContext: ThemedReactContext): CealGradientView {
        return CealGradientView(reactContext)
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "colors")
    fun configureView(view: CealGradientView, color: ReadableArray) {
        view.configureViews(color)
    }
}

<CealGradientView colors={[theme.Primary_50, theme.Information]} style={styles.linearGradient}>
<BorderButton text={EXISTING_USER} onPress={() => {}} isDarkMode={isDarkMode} />
    </CealGradientView>

const BorderButton = ({ text, isDarkMode, onPress }: Props) => {
  const theme = THEME_COLOR.SET(isDarkMode)

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.buttonStyle, { borderColor: theme.White }]} onPress={onPress}>
      <Text style={[styles.textStyle, { color: theme.White }]}>{text}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonStyle: {
    width: '100%',
    borderRadius: 8,
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  textStyle: {
    fontFamily: Fonts.InterSemiBold,
    fontSize: 16,
    lineHeight: 48,
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
  },
})
```

I have trying following [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17968) issue and tried some of the solutions mentioned but no luck

Sample reo https://github.com/PritishSawant/NativeAndroidLinearGradient

I have also tried adding following code but it does not work

```
private fun setupLayout() {
        Choreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(object: Choreographer.FrameCallback {
            override fun doFrame(frameTimeNanos: Long) {
                manuallyLayoutChildren()
                viewTreeObserver.dispatchOnGlobalLayout()
                Choreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(this)
            }
        })
    }

    /**
     * Layout all children properly
     */
    private fun manuallyLayoutChildren() {
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val child = getChildAt(i)
            child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(measuredWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(measuredHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY))
            child.layout(0, 0, child.measuredWidth, child.measuredHeight)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if your problem solved with commenting width, so instead of {{width:'100%'}} use {{width}} =>

```
const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');
```

Comment: The problem get solved by commenting and uncommenting any of the styles of the button, not necessarily the width

Answer (score 0):

I already encountered a similar problem, but working in Java. So i'll try my best to help you but my code may contains mistakes.

I resolved it by adding self measuring logic to my Layout, you can try adding it too and see if it helps.

Add the following methods to your CealGradientView class :

```kotlin
override fun requestLayout() {
    super.requestLayout()
    post(measureAndLayout)
}

private val measureAndLayout = Runnable {
    measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY))
    layout(left, top, right, bottom)
}
```

see [this old SO answer for Java equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39838774/12176221), hope it helps !

Comment: I have already tried this and it does not work for my use case.

Comment: Check the sample repo https://github.com/PritishSawant/NativeAndroidLinearGradient. I tried adding your code and it does not work

Comment: Tried booting your sample, but could not get it to work like you described. Fast reload does nothing

Comment: What issue are you facing? You have to comment the style once and save and then uncomment it back again.

Comment: you mean the whole style or only width as you said earlier ? Tried only width and didn't work as expected

Comment: just try the width

Comment: Same result as first try. When I run your sample, Hello button isn't even the same color as yours. Check your repo and i'll try again

Comment: Color has not anything do with it. I assigned some random colours just to I could quickly reproduce a small repo for reference